# Highcahrt Stock Chart Data Labels

Tags: highcharts

I am using `High-chart` Stock chart (Column) But i am unable to change its `dataLabel`

Where it shows Month name(Jan, Feb etc..) i want to show my custom names none of the `dataLabel` method is working.

> ```
> series:[{
>      name: 'My Label',
>      data: this.myData,
>      type:'column'
>
>  }]
> ```

It does't show text 'My Label', instead it shows names of months

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Tn8Tw/
```

Comment: The datalabels is related with points, but you dont display it in your chart. So "My Label" from series obejct should be visible in the tooltip?

Comment: Yes but what i want is to display my custom labels for series.

Comment: You can use tooltip formatter and customise content. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter